# Filter not working when filtering an array in an object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, filter

I'm trying to filter an array of strings

```
unfollow(handle: any) {
  let following = this.user?.following || [];
  following.filter((userHandle) => userHandle !== handle);
  console.log(following);
}
```

I want to filter the array of following in user object but when I `console.log(following)` the array is unchanged. I tried different things including this `this.user?.following?.filter((userHandle) => userHandle !== handle);` but nothing is filtered out

Comment: @froston A user is following 2 players `this.user?.following = ["ronaldo", "messi"]` then for example this user decides to `unfollow("messi")` so I simply want to update the array by filtering "messi" out

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign filtered output to someother variable. Filter will return the new array which contains filtered result

```
unfollow(handle: any) {
  let following = this.user?.following || [];
 let newArray =  following.filter((userHandle) => userHandle !== handle);
  console.log(newArray);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Array.filter` returns a new array instead of mutating the existing one.

Try:

```js
unfollow(handle: any) {
  let following = this.user?.following || [];
  let filtered = following.filter((userHandle) => userHandle !== handle);
  console.log(filtered);
}
```

or without the optional chaining:

```js
unfollow(handle: any) {
  if (this.user) {
    let following = this.user.following || [];
    let filtered = following.filter((userHandle) => userHandle !== handle);
    this.user.following = filtered
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I'm missing, but now how can I update `this.user?.following`? If I try to do this `this.user?.following = filtered` I will get this error `The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.`

Comment: That seems to be another issue. You would have to assign it to `this.user.following` avoiding the `?` optional chaining operator.

Comment: Updated the answer according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation for [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter),

> The filter() method **creates a new array** with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Therefore, you need to store the output of the `filter()` to use it anywhere else, including `console.log()`.

`let filtered = following.filter((userHandle) => userHandle !== handle);`